# Remove ActiveX controls automatically via Power Automate?

Tags: excel, activex, onedrive, power-automate, office-scripts

I have a process that requires me to take an Excel file that has ActiveX controls in it, and upload it into a database. I am trying to automate this in a flow by uploading the file to OneDrive, and then manipulating the document and extracting the required data. This doesn't work for me because it has ActiveX controls in the document.

I noticed when opening the document, it gives the option of opening a copy of the document, and then removes the ActiveX controls. This is the only solution that I see. I don't see any information on this being automated.

Is there a way that Power Automate can remove the ActiveX controls in an Excel document?

[image: Unsupported Features]

Comment: I can speak to the "office-scripts" tag and say there's no way to remove ActiveX controls through an Office Script.

What's your end goal? Do you need the version with ActiveX controls in either the OneDrive or the original location?

Comment: I am trying to run a flow in Power Automate that uses Office Scripts, but it won't successfully access the document due to the ActiveX controls